# Linear model of diodes for mesh current and nodal voltage analysis?

Tags: current, diodes, linear, mesh-analysis, nodal-analysis

If we use the piecewise linear model for diodes, can we apply mesh current and nodal voltage analysis to a circuit containing a diode?

Comment: Provide an example problem and your goal. I don't see why one should "write a book" on the topic. Narrow the scope a bit and allow a concrete example to be addressed. Otherwise? The general answer is just "yes" if by "piecewise linear model" you mean what I'm thinking in my head. But that's useless. What's in my head? And what's in yours when you write that phrase? We need a sharper focus, I think. I very rarely (only a very few times in my life) down-vote. But this is one of those few cases that tempted me given how vague it is, yet pretending towards a specificity it actually lacks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. KCL (all current entering node must leave the node) and KVL (voltage around a loop sums to zero) still hold, regardless of the branch constituent equations.

The branch constituent equations change. While you're usually accustomed to seeing resistors (V = IR), current sources (I = some constant), and voltage sources (V = some constant), you will now have apply the piecewise linear model of the diode as a branch constituent equation. You can also use an even more accurate model such as an exponential model.

The overall system is no longer linear, so the problem will not be immediately solvable using pure linear techniques (such as Gaussian elimination, inversion of the matrix found in [modified nodal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_nodal_analysis), etc.).

Answer (score 0):

No, a piece-wise linear model is still not a fully linear model. You can only use the PWL model if you know *a priori* which linear piece represents the current state.

You can make an **assumption** about which piece of the PWL model is where the diode is operating, but you must check the final result of your analysis to verify that it is consistent with your assumption. If not, try a different assumption.